# Why won't my radio button change checked state, like a toggle button (Android)?

Tags: android, radio-button, toggle, togglebutton

For the purpose of ascetics, I need to use a radio button as a toggle button. Unfortunately, I can only get it to either stay checked or uncheck but not recheck. I've tried every combination I can think of and cannot get it to work. toggle() won't work because it will only check an unchecked radio button. I've tried a combination of isChecker() and setChecked(), but it won't work. This is what I currently have:

```
    pi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            Log.e("Pistate before",Boolean.toString(pistate));

            if(pistate=true)
                pi.setChecked(false);
            if(pistate=false)
                pi.setChecked(true);
            if(pi.isChecked())
                pistate=true;
            if(!pi.isChecked())
                pistate=false;

            Log.e("Pistate after",Boolean.toString(pistate));
        }
    });
```

Once unchecked, it won't recheck. pistate reads false both before and after which makes absolutely no sense since my if() should change it, right?

Comment: == is the answer. http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html (scroll to number 8)

Comment: You can reduce your code to 1 line: pi.setChecked(!pi.isChecked());   if you need to know what pistate is elsewhere in your app add the line pistate = pi.isChecked(); under it

Comment: @dymmeh : Just spotted your comment. You beat me to it.

Comment: Yes, the == was wrong, but not the problem. It was correct in my actual code. Squonk's comment worked exactly like I wanted it to. Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to maintain the 'state' using a separate `Boolean` just do the following...

```
pi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pi.setChecked(!pi.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Always going back to same state.

Answer (score 4):

Well since it's a comparison, you should be using `==`

`if(pistate == true)`

Or if it's an object reference you want

`if(object.equals(pistate))`

Answer (score 1):

Well is the same that I would say. 
Using == will help.
Never the less the method is more complicated as it could be.
I would advise:

```
pi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {               
        Log.e("Pistate before",Boolean.toString(pistate));

        pistate = !pistate;
        pi.setChecked(pistate);

        Log.e("Pistate after",Boolean.toString(pistate));
    }
});
```